# ASP.NET MVC save data between controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, controller, parameter-passing

Assume the following scenario. You have three controllers:

1. `getFirstData`
2. `getSecondData`
3. `useFirstData`

The workflow of your site requires that the user first uses the `getFirstData` controller, and inputs some data (let's say an int) in the view.
I then need to use the second controller (`getSecondData`) for something else.
Only then does he use the third controller (`useFirstData`), and needs the original data he inputted in the first controller.

What is the most appropriate way to hang on to that data?

I can pass it along in the model I created through the controllers, but that requires me to "update" the value I pass inside the views, which seems "hackish".

A global variable seems "wrong".

What is the standard way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use dictionary **TempData**

Comment: I'm not too happy with this solution, but it's too late to change the entire flow. I mean, it's never too late, but it's too much of a hassle and isn't worth it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to create a wizard type workflow. Here are some other questions which might help.

[How do I make a wizard with asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297148/how-to-make-a-wizard-with-asp-net-mvc)
[How do I handle page flow in MVC, particularly asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330/how-do-i-handle-page-flow-in-mvc-particularly-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

Just save to the database between each step.

If you don't want to do a round-trip, try a JQuery Wizard plugin, [like this one.](http://worcesterwideweb.com/2007/06/04/jquery-wizard-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a Wizard and you're using jQuery give a look to [jWizard](http://dominicbarnes.us/jWizard). It rocks!